# Change style of repeater item in codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, repeater

just wondering if there is a way to change the style/css of repeateritems from the codebehind. Basically I have a printer friendly version of a page and if the display is printer friendly i want to add a bottom margin to each item in the repeater. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to do within the [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) event of the Repeater.

```
   protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
        ((HtmlControl)e.Item.FindControl("SomeControl")).Attributes.Add("class", "cssStyle");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several options to apply styles, hae a look at thee Repeater's [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) event.

codebehind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim tbl As New DataTable
        tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn())
        For i As Int32 = 1 To 10
            tbl.Rows.Add(tbl.NewRow)
            tbl.Rows(tbl.Rows.Count - 1)(0) = "Item " & i
        Next
        Me.Repeater1.DataSource = tbl
        Me.Repeater1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemDataBound
    Select Case e.Item.ItemType
        Case ListItemType.Item, ListItemType.AlternatingItem
            Dim dr = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)
            Dim Label1 = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("Label1"), Label)
            Label1.Text = dr(0)
            'use CssClass property'
            Label1.CssClass = "MyClass"
            'use Style property'
            Label1.Style.Add("color", "red")
            'use direct properties, for example'
            Label1.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow
    End Select
End Sub
```

aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate><table></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. What are you repeating ? a `<TR>` ? a `<DIV>` ?

Just change the CssClass from code behind ... ex : YourRepeatedItem.CssClass = "PrinterFriendly".

```
For each ReaptedItem as repeaterItem in YourRepeater.items
    dim ItemToBeModified as htmlcontrol = RepeatedItem.findControl("ControlID")
    ItemToBeModified.CssClass = "PrinterFriendly"
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to change styles of any control from the codebehind. Basically the **WebControl** class ( the parent of all the asp.net UI controls ) is having the **CssClass** property and many other properties that expose the style behaviors. By changing them you can change the look.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to make use of the 'media' property that is available in style sheets: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmedia.shtml

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

OR

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print {
    .XXX{margin-bottom:5px;}
}
</style>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="XXX" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```